# neighbours PC on my Wifi

Tags: wireless-networking, ip-address, netsend

Well i can't put a password on my wifi, because everytime I do that the connection drops every 5 minutes or so on all wired and wireless PCs. I'm not happy about it but I keep a check of all the computers that connect to it

Well I've just found a PC that isn't one of mine on the network and I'd like to get more info about, such as what OS it is (this would give me a better understanding of which neighbour it is). And even possibly send a message to them.

How can I go about this, I can't use 3rd party software as I don't have access to the PC as it's my neighbours.

I could just block their Mac Address but frankly that would be less fun.

So how do I find out more info using their ip address (or Mac address)? And is it possible to message them (something like netsend, though I'm pretty sure the computer is not XP as it shows up on network Map)

Comment: I'd investigate the problem with the password on your wifi - having an unsecured access point could leave you open to sanctions, even prosecution, if they do something illegal using it.

Comment: What? Nobody came up with the Upside-Down-Ternet and the XKCD-Comic by now? Well, then let me do that: http://www.ex-parrot.com/pete/upside-down-ternet.html http://www.xkcd.org/341/

Comment: How did you detect another computer - did you see it on the router's DHCP?  Did you net use and see something you didn't expect?

Comment: Well I saw it on the network panel in the Control Panel but also saw a Mac address on the router that I didn't recognize.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use nmap to scan your wireless network, it will give a lot of useful information:

```
nmap -v -O YOURNETWORKIPRANGE
```

Comment: I'm on windows btw, as it says nmap is not a valid command

Comment: There is a windows version with GUI that you can get from here http://nmap.org/download.html

Comment: Note: Don't attack/block anything on your nettwork that isn't your computer. (Your wifi router and modem will show up in the scan, you don't want to kick those out of your network) As suggested above, fixing your security issue is a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

Try a `nbtstat -A [IP]`.

If you really want to know that much, just open up Wireshark (or any packet sniffer) and check on what they're doing.

Comment: that doesn't any new information.

Comment: your comment incomplete

Answer (score 0):

This is by no means as good as a fully encrypted network.

If you really like messing with your neigbours... try looking here: http://www.ex-parrot.com/pete/upside-down-ternet.html

Most routers are Linux based and some have a command line interface that you can enter commands at to achieve the desired effect.  Some extra tools on your main machine may be needed...